# convert string timestamp to ISO 8601 compliant string

Tags: java, date, jodatime, iso8601

I have a timestamp and offset in string format as shown below in two different variables:

```
01/14/2016 07:37:36PM
-08:00
```

I want to convert above timestamp into `ISO 8601 compliant String, with milliseconds and timezone` so it should look like this after conversion:

```
2016-01-14T19:37:36-08:00
```

How can I do that? I am using jodatime library.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Fromwhere would you think you couldget the milliseconds? They aren’t even in the ISO-8601 string you say you want.

Comment: That `-08:00` is an offset-from-UTC, *not* a time zone. A time zone is a history of the changes to a region’s offset. Ex: `America/Montreal` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

Comment: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its team advises moving to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer `java.time` classes work so well with ISO 8601 strings.

```
    String dateTimeString = "01/14/2016 07:37:36PM"; 
    String offsetString = "-08:00";

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ssa"));
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(offsetString);
    String formattedTimestamp = dateTime.atOffset(offset).toString();
    System.out.println(formattedTimestamp);
```

This prints

```
2016-01-14T19:37:36-08:00
```

Stay away from outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat`.

What is `offsetString` is not present? I understand that in this case you want an offset of `Z` for UTC. For example like this:

```
    ZoneOffset offset;
    if (offsetString == null) {
        offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
    } else {
        offset = ZoneOffset.of(offsetString);
    }
    String formattedTimestamp = dateTime.atOffset(offset).toString();
```

With a `null` `offsetString` we now get

```
2016-01-14T19:37:36Z
```

The classes in `java.time` (of which I’m using but a few) are described in JSR-310 and come built-in with Java 8. What if you would like to use them with Java 6 or 7? You get the ThreeTen Backport (link below). It gives you the majority of the classes for Java 6 and 7. I’m not perfectly happy to tell you you need an external library, but in this case it’s only until you move to Java 8. I hope you will soon.

I am sure it can be done with JodaTime too, but I haven’t got experience with it, so cannot give you the details there. What I do know, I have read the the folks behind JodaTime now recommend you move over to `java.time` instead. So I am asking you to swap one external library for a newer (and supposedly better) one. In itself I’m not unhappy with that. Only if you already have a codebase that uses JodaTime, it’s not really trivial.

Link: [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)

Comment: Is there any way to use without Java 8?

Comment: I only have problem with ZoneId since that I cannot locate.

Comment: Also what happens let's say if offsetString is not present? In that case I just want to return this `2016-01-14T21:16:54Z` without any offset. This is another example where offfset was not present.

Comment: In ISO-8601, `Z` counts as a (zero) offset (from UTC). I have edited the answer to show how we handle that (I have also simplified the original code a bit). @user1950349

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph… Adding ThreeTen-Backport does not require removing Joda-Time. Both libraries can exist within one project. Just be careful with `import` statements as some class names may be present in both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more examples in section Examples at :- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String string2 = "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00";
Date result2 = df2.parse(string2);
```

Comment: How will I do this in my example?