# How to get start and end range from list of timestamps?

Tags: java, sorting, date, jodatime

I have a timestamp string like this:

```
2016-01-14T22:43:55Z
2016-01-15T00:04:50Z
2016-01-15T00:44:59+08:30
2016-01-15T01:25:35-05:00
2016-01-15T01:44:31+08:30
2016-01-15T02:22:45-05:00
2016-01-15T02:54:18-05:00
2016-01-15T03:53:26-05:00
2016-01-15T04:32:24-08:00
2016-01-15T06:31:32Z
2016-01-15T07:06:07-05:00
```

I want to sort them so that I can get what is starting range and ending range from above timestamp. I am doing like below:

```
List<String> timestamp = new ArrayList<>();
// adding above string timestamp into this list
// now sort it
Collections.sort(timestamp);
```

This will give me start and end range from the above list of timestamp. Is this the right way to do it or there is any better way?

```
timestamp.get(0); // start range
timestamp.get(timestamp.size() - 1); // end range
```

**Update**

So I should do something like below:

```
List<OffsetDateTime> timestamp = new ArrayList<>();
timestamp.add(OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-15T00:44:59+08:30" ));
// add other timestamp string like above and then sort it
Collections.sort(timestamp);

timestamp.get(0); // start range
timestamp.get(timestamp.size() - 1); // end range
```

Comment: All the timestamps are not in the same timezones. Sorting them alphabetically won't sort them chronologically. Parse them to Instants, and sort the Instants (or just find the min and the max: the Collections class also has methods to do that).

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` is the right class to use for those strings. No need to convert explicitly to `Instant` since `OffsetDateTime` is comparable and orders primarily by point on a time line, that is, instant (and secondly by zone offset). See Basil Bourque’s answer. @JBNizet (I agree of course that sorting as strings won’t give the correct order)

Comment: If you only need the first and the last in the sorted order, you may use `Collections.min()` and `Collections.max()` rather than `Collections.sort()`. If there are many timestamps, this will also be more efficient. The trick also works with the answers posted until now.

Comment: If those timestamps come out of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698451/convert-string-timestamp-to-iso-8601-compliant-string), why not just keep the `ZonedDateTime` objects you had there rather than the strings? Then sorting, or just finding the first and the last, will be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse those [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings into `java.time.OffsetDateTime` objects.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-15T00:44:59+08:30" )
```

Add those date-time objects to a `Collection` and sort. You probably want a `List` such as `ArrayList` or a `SortedSet`.

The java.time classes implement the `compareTo` method, to fulfill their contract as a [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). So these objects know how to sort.

Like this:

```
List<OffsetDateTime> odts = new ArrayList<>();

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-15T00:44:59+08:30" ) ;
odts.add( odt );
… // Parse remaining ISO 8601 strings, adding each new OffsetDateTime object to collection.

Collections.sort( odts );
```

Comment: got it now.. updated my question with details.. this is the way I should do now?

Comment: I should say it is. If you experience any issues with it, please revert, and I’m sure there’s a couple of us wanting to take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **Comparator**.
First of all create a class and implement `Comparator`. And then compare value1 and value2 with your choice. After that use this class to **Collections.sort**.

Regards, a.ayati

Comment: No need to implement your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Parse the ISO 8601 strings into java.time objects which already know how to sort.