# SimpleDateFormat throwing Unparseable exception

Tags: java

I know there are alot of these, but I can'e seem to find the magic string for this date format:

```
String textDate = "2018-04-25T18:23:57.556Z";
```

My code is:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
simpleDateFormat.parse(textDate)
```

What's weird is there is a "Z" in the date string itself, so I am not sure how the timezone works on this one.

If I change the date format to:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
```

It works,  but I am not sure how to get the time zone then...

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Always **search Stack Overflow** before posting. Most any date-time question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: `Z` = UTC ➡ [`java.time.Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @BasilBourque, I did plenty of searches,  for SimpleDateFormat,  what I needed to search was for ISO 8601,  which I did not know was the format.

Comment: You are correct that you shouldn’t quote the `Z` in the format pattern string since this is the UTC offset and must be parsed as such to get the correct result.

Comment: You are correct that there are a lot of these. [Here’s just one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/string-to-date-time-object-in-android) If you tell us what trouble you had with those, I am sure we can and will guide you from there.

Comment: You may also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709133/how-to-get-start-and-end-range-from-list-of-timestamps), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142198/string-date-into-epoch-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666263/java-date-parsing-why-do-i-get-an-error) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368493/how-to-parse-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssxxx-date-format-to-simple-in-android).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Z` = UTC

The literal "Z" is actually part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime standard for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) times. When "Z" (Zulu) is tacked on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC, so really the literal `Z` is part of the time.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in UTC, a perfect fit for your input string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-04-25T18:23:57.556Z" ) ;
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: @shmosel I added a bit of *java.time* code to make the Answer more useful.